# ¿como pasar un Array PHP de una consulta a una función Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, array

Quisiera saber como pasar el array asociativo $data[] a una funcion javascript dentro de un `<button>` sin tener que estar colocando a cada rato `$data[]`, es decir:
Primero hago mi consulta

```
<?php
        $resultado=mvcontrolador::listadoTablaControlador("t_cliente",null);
        foreach ($resultado as $indice => $data) { ?>
```

Muestro los campos en una tabla:

```
<tr id="campos">
            <td><?php echo $data['nombre_cliente'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['apellido_cliente'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['cedula_cliente'];?></td>          
            <td><?php echo $data['correo_cliente'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['telf_cliente'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['estado'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['codigopostal'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['localidad'];?></td>
```

`Y donde quiero que dichos valores del array sean insertados en una funcion 
dentro de un``

```
<form method="POST">
<td> <button type="button" value=""
onclick='return verInfoCliente("<?php echo $data['id_cliente'];?>");'
name="infoCliente" >Info</button></td> <?php } ?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer ahora es usar dentro de una funcion que está en un archivo js aparte:

> function verInfoCliente(){}

Que muestre un alert con todos los datos de mi array sin tener que colocar manualmente todos los datos del array por separado. 
Sin tener que hacer esto:

```
verInfoCliente("<?php echo $data['id_cliente'],
$data['nombre_cliente'],
$data['apellido_cliente'],
$data['cedula_cliente'],
$data['correo_cliente'],
$data['telf_cliente'];?>");
```

Y la funcion javascript:

```
function verinfocliente(id,nombre,apellido,cedula,correo,telf){
alert('Los datos del cliente son: \nNombre:'+nombre+'\nApe... ');
}
```

etc...

Quiero es pasar ese array PHP a la `funcion()` javascript y dentro de esa `funcion()` usar ese array en mi `alert()`.

espero que se dé a entender lo que quiero exponer, gracias de antemano.

Comment: este código tiene errores tipográficos, corrigelos porfa ;) Ademas estaría guai que colgases algo mas completo y seguido y no fragmentos tan discontinuos.

Comment: Cada que juntas `PHP` y `JavaScript` de esa forma, muere un gatito, le cae un rayo a una abuelita y atropellan un perrito :C Así que por favor no lo hagas, echale un vistazo a `AJAX`, es la mejor forma de trabajar `JS` y `PHP` en conjunto

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tenga buenas respuestas. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento básico del sitio. En cuanto a tu pregunta veo que tienes una función verinfocliente que la mandas llamar con un nombre diferente verInfoCliente ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directamente no puedes pasarlo de array `php` a array `javascript`, pero si puedes pasarlo directamente de array `php` a `json`, es decir un `objeto json` en `javascript`.

En PHP aplica la función `json_encode` al array.

Según tu código seria:

```
verInfoCliente("<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>");
```

Funcion `javascript` recibe el objeto, se obtienen los valores interpretando el `json`:

```
function verinfocliente(datos){
    alert('Los datos del cliente son: \nNombre:'+datos.nombre_cliente+'\nApe... ');
}
```

Finalmente si deseas que sea estrictamente un `array` de `javascript` (mas no un `json`) deberías creas un función personalizada en `php`, pero a estas alturas no es necesario complicarse. Suerte

Comment: Ahora Si, gracias por tu respuesta juliocpiro
lo que quería era eso, porque en esa tabla se muestran muchos datos, lo que quería era reducirlo pasando ese array, ahora con esa funcion json_encode, no se me ocurrió colocarla dentro de la función `verInfoCliente("<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>");` dentro del `<button>`.
Si, lo sé me hace falta aprender mucho de javascript, estoy especializándome en PHP primero, por eso a veces es mucho mejor pedir ayuda que golpear tu cabeza con el teclado jejeje.

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió, dame mi +1 :). Suerte

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir las variables así en JS y así no tener que llamar al PHP cada vez:

```
<script>
 var data = <?php echo json_encode($data);?>;
</script>

<form method="POST">
<td> <button type="button" value=""
onclick='return verInfoCliente(data.id_cliente);'
name="infoCliente" >Info</button></td> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: ¿y como hago para hacer un array js usando el array PHP?
¿Yo puedo hacer algo así como?:
<script>
var arraycliente = <?php echo $data; ?>;
</script>

Comment: Así: arraycliente = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;

Answer (score 0):

Así quedó mí funcion al hacer click en `<button type="button" onclick="verInfoCliente("<?php echo json_encode($data);?>")">`:

`function verInfoCliente(datos){
    if (confirm('Infomacion del Cliente. \nNombres: '+datos.nombre_cliente+
                                            '\nApellidos: '+datos.apellido_cliente+
                                            '\nCedula: '+datos.cedula_cliente+
                                            '\nCorreo: '+datos.correo_cliente+
                                            '\nTelefono: '+datos.telf_cliente+
                                            '\nEstado: '+datos.estado+
                                            '\nCodigo Postal: '+datos.codigopostal+
                                            '\nLocalidad: '+datos.localidad+
                                            '\nFecha de registro: '+datos.fecha_reg+
                                            '\n\n¿Desea editar este cliente?')) {
        alert('Asegurese de que los datos sean los correctos.');
        window.location.href="editarCliente&idCliente="+datos.id_cliente;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}`
Graficamente me muestra esto :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos por su ayuda!